# Java String; Able to allocate the size of the string given a size?

Tags: java, string

Tried searching in the Java String API with no answer.

I am trying to create Java strings with a specified size.  I noticed that Java Strings do not end in the null character (\0).  Basically, I would like to be able to create strings such as:

```
String myString = new String("Charles", 32);
```

where myString will contain `"Charles      <-- 24 spaces -->                  \0"`

There is no such method that can achieve what I have above.  Should I just rely on creating my own function to do so?

Thanks

Comment: No need for `[]` after `String`, although you can use `char[]` similarly to `String` (still doesn't require a NUL terminator).

Comment: The above Java code declares an array of strings, but assigns it a single string as its value. You should probably edit the example to clarify your question.

Comment: The code you posted will not compile, because you declared `myString` as an *array* of `String` s, but then you assign a single `String` object to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String myString = String.format("%1$-" + 32 + "s", "Charles");
```

Comment: Nice solution. Didn't think of that possibility.

Comment: @Carlo - Null safety, if "Charles" was replaced with null, it will print the word null instead of giving a Null Pointer Exception

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Java are immutable.  If you want those extra spaces at the end, you're simply going to have to create a string that contains those spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there probably isn't a built in function for that. You could pad the string to the required length using String.format() and then append a \0 to the end of it - that should do what you want fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to work with fixed size strings in a mutable way, you could also write your own wrapper that encapsulates a presized char[], e.g.

```
public class MyString()
 private char[] values;

 public MyString(int size)
 {
   values=new char[size];
 }

 ... methods to set, get

 public String toString() { return new String(values);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would you one of the formatting options provided by Java to accomplish that.

For example implement your own [java.text.Format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Format.html) implementation.

Another possibility would be to use a StringBuffer/StringBuilder with the specified capacity and initialize it with spaces and the \0. Then you can fiddle with the char positions when writing/modifying the text.